# Android load libs from wrong location

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

I have 2 C shared libs liba.so and libb.so where jnis compiled within liba.so and dynamically linked with libb.so.
while loading liba.so using:System.loadLibrary("a") android tried to link it with /my/local_machine/project/app/src/main//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libb.so

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed:
library "/my/local_machine/project/app/src/main//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libb.so" not found.
```

instead of search at libs directory!
I compiled liba using **androidMK** and normal **cross compilation** for libb

Comment: Did you try to also add "System.loadLibrary("b")" ?

Comment: the ndk-depend output is:
libtabernacle_l.so
libclang_rt.asan-aarch64-android.so
libm.so
liblog.so
libc++_shared.so
libdl.so
libc.so
/my/local_machine/project/app/src/main//obj/local/arm64-v8a/libb.so

Comment: Make sure that the path to your liba.so and libb.so is correct in your CMakeList.txt. Also i'm a bit confused due to "//" instead of "/" in the error message

Comment: I used **android.mk** to compile liba.so not **cmake**